# Decision boundary for linear kernel(svm) is wrong

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Why my decision line is not correctly represented in a graph, for the linear classification with svm

```
w = clf.coef_[0]


a = -w[0] / w[1]


XX = np.linspace(10, 30)

yy = a * XX - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1]


plt.plot(XX, yy, 'k-')


plt.scatter(X_train[:, 0], X_train[:, 1], c=y_train)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: The formula looks OK.  What are the values of `coef_` and `intercept_`?

Comment: this sample code is from tutorial, i am not sure how to modify it for my data, do u know how?should i change coed and intercept?

Comment: Maybe provide the rest of the code?  You shouldn't manually change those, just fit the svm.